# How to enable and disable MVC Required Field validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to enable and disable the required field validation based on anchor tag click.

Here I showed some example

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomText)
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CustomText)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomText, null, new { @style = "color:red" })
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SelectOn();" class="button">ON</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SelectOff();" class="button">OFF</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var modVal = '@Modle.IsEnabled';
            if (modVal = 'false') {
                //Need to disable
            }
        });

        function SelectOn() {
            //Need to enable
        }

        function SelectOff() {
            //Need to disable
        }
</script>
```

Edit

That **CustomText** is my model property

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Custom Text")]
public string CustomText { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Does your property `CustomText` have a validation attribute? Are you wanting to enforce that validation only under certain circumstances?

Comment: That **CustomText** is my model  property

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Custom Text")]
        public string CustomText { get; set; }

Comment: No its not. Its a property in your model :) You should be using a `[RequiredIf]` or similar validation attribute so you get both server and client side validation (unlike the answer you accepted). Check out [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That code is working, That much I want. Thank you

Comment: Working is it? What happens when you post to the controller method? And I gave you a link :)

Comment: When posting time its having empty value.

Comment: Which means you model will be invalid because you have a `[Required]` attribute :)

Comment: No, model having empty/null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rules()` like

If you want to add rules, `rules('add',required);`

If you want to remove rules, `rules('remove','required');`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomText)
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CustomText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomText, null, new { @style = "color:red" })
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SelectOn();" class="button">ON</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SelectOff();" class="button">OFF</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var modVal = '@Modle.IsEnabled';
        if (modVal = 'false') {
            //Need to disable
            $('#CustomText').rules('remove');
            $('#CustomText-error').text('');
        }
    });

    function SelectOn() {
        //Need to enable
        $("#CustomText").rules("add", 'required');
    }

    function SelectOff() {
        //Need to disable
        $('#CustomText').rules('remove');
        $('#CustomText-error').text('');
    }
</script>
```